# error al realizar funcion de login con php

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un código en php el cual lo quiero consumir en android, el problema que tengo actualmente, es que al probar el código, tengo problemas con este, el error que tengo es a la hora de ejecutar la consulta con la varible "$result" de la funcion autenticar, ya que me entrega el siguiente mensaje de alerta

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

el codigo que tengo, es el siguiente:

```
class User {

        private $db;
        private $conexion;

        function __construct() {
            $this -> db = new Conexion();
            $this -> conexion= $this->db->obtenerConexion();
        }

        public function autenticar($email,$password){
            $jsonData= array();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE email='$email' and contraseña='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $jsonData['Estado'] [] = 'correcto';
                    $jsonData['nombre'] []=$row['nombre'];
                    $jsonData['codigo'][]= $row['codigo'];
                    $jsonData['foto'][]=$row['FotoPerfil'];
                }
          }
          else{  
                $jsonData['Estado'] = 'Error, credenciales invalidas';
            } 

            $json['Login_data']=$jsonData;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this -> conexion);
        }   
    }

    $user = new User();
    if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
            $user-> autenticar($email,$password);
        }else{
            $json['Estado'] = 'Error, campos vacios';
            echo json_encode($json);
        }

    }else{
            $json['Estado'] = 'Error, variables sin contenido de Post';
            echo json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: Creo que el fallo lo tienes a la hora de hacer la consulta, debe ir la tabla usuario entre comillas?

Comment: probe con y sin comillas y da el mismo error

Comment: Prueba a hacer un var_dump de $query antes de ejecutarla, y haz esa consulta directamente en tu phpmyadmin, o el gestor de base de datos que uses, para ver si el problema esta en la sentencia sql y saber cual es. Como ha dicho Mario, es probable que no te llegue nada a $result y estes pasando un parametro null a num_rows por que o bien la consulta esta mal, o la conexion a la bbdd es errónea.

Comment: hize lo del var_dump y copie el select en mysql y se ejecuto sin nigun problema

Comment: el problema creo que no es la consulta si no la variable $result

Comment: Y posiblemente utilizar la ñ en contraseña de fallo, prueba a cambiar el campo por password por ejemplo

Comment: efectivamente, era la ñ, si quieres puntos da una respuesta y la califico :D, me ayudaste demasiado, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la ñ de contraseña, cambia el nombre del campo por password por ejemplo. Me alegro de que funcione :)

Comment: gracias man, estuve trabado un par de horas por una sola letra, gracias nuevamente